# Gnome shell GLib async process become defunct

Tags: javascript, linux, glib, gnome

I'm writing a gnome shell extension and running a bash script with

```
let [, pid, , , ] = imports.gi.GLib.spawn_async(null, args, null, GLib.SpawnFlags.DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD, null);
```

which works, however after running a few times I'm able to see

```
ps aux | grep pid
```

the processes are there, and marked as defunct. Is this normal? Should I be cleaning up these processes? Or this is normal behavior?

The description of `GLib.spawn_async()` does say to call `GLib.spawn_close_pid()` but the description of that says:

> On some platforms, notably Windows, the GLib.Pid type represents a resource which must be closed to prevent resource leaking. GLib.spawn_close_pid is provided for this purpose. It should be used on all platforms, even though it doesn't do anything under UNIX.

My system is ubuntu, should I be calling `spawn_close_pid()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for [`G_SPAWN_DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Spawning-Processes.html#GSpawnFlags):

> the child will not be automatically reaped; you must use `g_child_watch_add()` yourself (or call `waitpid()` or handle `SIGCHLD` yourself), or the child will become a zombie.

So what’s happening is normal: the child process is being spawned, doing something, exiting and becoming defunct — but no parent process is reaping it. Dead processes hang around until reaped so that the parent process can check their exit status.

You need to either stop using the `GLib.SpawnFlags.DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD` flag (in which case GLib will watch for the child process exiting and will reap it automatically); or add a child watch handler yourself using [`g_child_watch_add()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-child-watch-add) and reap the defunct process in the [`GChildWatchFunc`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#GChildWatchFunc) callback using [`g_spawn_close_pid()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Spawning-Processes.html#g-spawn-close-pid).

There’s an example [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606042/trying-to-execute-shell-command-by-g-spawn-async-and-read-the-output) or [another here](http://blog.borovsak.si/2009/07/spawning-processes-using-glib.html).

Comment: Removing that flag did it. Thanks!